# /data/tmp on database server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, database, command-line-interface

I am on a Linux **ubuntu** machine with **MySQL** installed.

My teacher gave out an assignment which mentioned "**copy cars.dat to /data/tmp on the MySQL database server**" without any explanations, I do not know what is the "**/data/tmp on database server**" means exactly?

Basically after that I need to execute SQL statement like

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/data/tmp/cars.dat' INTO TABLE cars
```

So, what does **copy cars.dat to /data/tmp on the database server** means as there is no /data/tmp directory even?

Personally, I checked `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file, inside which there are definitions of :

```
...
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
...
```

Does it mean to copy cars.dat to the `tmpdir` which is just `/tmp` under root directory??

Comment: It's home work, so explain what are the possibilies you examined before post !

Comment: @ Dom, I updated my post which includes what I examined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, sounds like he's used to a Solaris system maybe?

I'd say do one of:

1. copy cars.dat to a directory of your choice (your home, /tmp, etc) and change the path in LOAD DATA INFILE
2. create /data/tmp with `sudo mkdir -p /data/tmp` and carry on
3. ask your teacher
4. dog ate my homework

Comment: +1, dog ate my homework.